# 'TypeError: can't access property "split", response.specificCosmeticFilters.injectedCSS is undefined' error occuouring on all sites

Tags: firefox

I am getting the following error on all sites

```
TypeError: can't access property "split", response.specificCosmeticFilters.injectedCSS is undefined
```

The error is occouring at

```
moz-extension://2f64ccfe-42ad-4603-97e0-f55ef30a6645/js/contentscript.js
```

Im using firefox developer edition 107.0b9 (64-bit)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: When I run the code, I don't get any error.

Comment: @i-drink-dirty-code it may be a browser issue, however this is the only time I have ever encountered the issue. I was wondering if it was some issue with my code

Comment: There isn't an issue with the code you provided, nor does the code provided even attempt to use the `split()` method at any point. Thus the error is coming from something else, likely a plugin installed in your browser. The closest reference I could find to that error is **uBlock Origin**, which is a browser extension that does seem to use *cosmetic filtering* and applies CSS to hide elements (*ads*)

Comment: @EssXTee I have tried uninstalling uBlock Origin however the same issue occours

Comment: This is a very difficult thing to troubleshoot because there are too many unknown factors. uBlock Origin was just an example (and guess), but there are possibly a number of extensions that could cause an issue, not to mention the configuration of the browser and any extensions. If running the same code in an incognito/private window, or another browser entirely, does not yield the same error, you know the issue is specific to your installation of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
After copying the moz-extention code into the browser, it revealed that it was caused by [AdNauseum](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/adnauseam/)
Sorry everybody